# Android 8.1 GApps

Tags: google-play-services, 8.1-oreo

So basically, I've flashed a rom onto my phone, specifically lineage 15.1, for the reasoning of I like Android 8.1. The problem, however, is that my gapps seem to not work. Google Play services stop respond legitimately every 5 seconds, and I've seen all the stuff about force stopping it and cleaning the cache, but those options are greyed out for me. My phone is a Galaxy Note 3, if that makes a difference. Also, it wants me to do the Pixel setup, but it checks for updates continuously forever. What to do?

Comment: have you downloaded gapps from here: https://opengapps.org/. you can download and install pico version from there. pico installs google play app, and you can later install other google apps. you can also install other versions also, which depends upon your system space.

Comment: That is quite literally exactly what I installed, yes. Even right down to the pico version, that was what I chose.

Answer (score 0):

Did you do a "clean flash" (= wipe /data partition) when flashing your ROM ? Or did you do a "dirty flash" (do NOT wipe /data partition) ?

If you did a dirty flash, my advice is to do a clean flash instead, then reinstall LineageOS + OpenGApps (pico version as advised by @Rahul Gopi). Be aware that it will reset your phone (non-system apps, settings, etc. except your USB storage/card).

Answer (score 0):

As breversa says, you should do a clean flash. However if you don't want to loose all your non-system apps and settings you could first try to wipe /system and then install LOS 15.1 again, flash the Gapps after and clear (Dalvik) Cache, no need to wipe /data. If that fixes the crashes, great. If it does not, you should indeed try a clean flash.